# How to display fully visible Items in top of the Listview after scrolling?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, visibility

how to proceed forward in the `listview`. i am having `listitem` consists of 30 items which displaying only `images`.

In visible screen we can able to see minimum 1 1/2 images per screen(ie., one full image and half of the second Image).. When I scrolling the `listview`, many times it happen top item in the `listview` is partially visible(i.e., only half can be seen). So i want restrict that in the `listview` ...After Scrolling i want display only fully visible items in top of the `Listview`, avoiding partially visible items in top of the `listview`.

Can anyone help me. Please suggest any ides to solve this issues.

Comment: Use List of 2 ImageView and you can have your image in one imageview and the next view let it be blank with a white background and by this you can desired result. Use Custom Adapter

Comment: I doubt this will somehow enhance user's experience. User is already familiar in how listview scrolling works.

Comment: If the image covers around 66% of the screen, I would consider another type of view to scroll through the images, like a ViewPager. There are numerous libraries that have various implementations of displaying images in lists, grids, etc

Comment: According to my issue, there is no problem in if i able to see half of the image in the bottom of the listview, only restrict in top of the listview to enhance user experience only,, but this could not be happen what you hva told like two imageview and all....@therealprashant

Comment: now i can can able to get first visible item index in top of the listview ,after that based on index of an item .... how to move forward through this or tell me this is not for work for me based on index like that ...reply for this ...@ biegleux

Comment: check AbsListView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop() or similar methods

Answer (score 2):

```
mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    }
});
```

Comment: i am also did same as you ...like

Comment: This works, although sometimes ```mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()``` gives me the wrong position. I ended up using an integer to keep track of the position I wanted to scroll to

Answer (score 0):

Finally i am got it based on setSelection() method.

```
mainListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        //int currentTopVisible;
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            int index=mainListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            mainListView.setSelection(index);
```

}
            }

```
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }
    });
```